# PHP and cURL - Multiform request with file and text

Tags: php, curl, upload

I need to send a cURL request containing a file to upload as well as a JSON string. I can get a properly formatted request when sending the JSON, but the file is throwing it off.

```
    $postData = array(
        'JSON'=> json_encode($jsonParams),
        $reference => '@'.$tmp_file_path
    );

    //Borrowed function from: http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/php-curl-multipart-form-posting.html
    function multipart_build($fields, $boundary){
        $retval = '';
        foreach($fields as $key => $value){
            $retval .= "--$boundary\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$key\"\n\n$value\n";
        }
        $retval .= "--$boundary--";
        return $retval;
    }

    $boundary = "--requestboundary-xxx";
    $request = $this->multipart_build($postData,$boundary);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

The $reference needs to be tied to a value in the $jsonParams so the receiving server can ensure uploaded files are attached to the corresponding data string packages.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Update after Marc B's comment

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So my first approach wasn't using my own multipart. The reason I went with multipart was at least I was getting a response from the server. Here is the original code.

```
    $curl_file_object = curl_file_create($attachmentFile['tmp_name'], $attachmentFile['type'], $reference);

    $postData= array(
        'JSON'=> json_encode($jsonParams),
        $reference => $curl_file_object,
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // enable posting
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); // post data
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if any redirection after upload

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    debug($info);
```

And with this I get:

```
[url] => --------
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.031
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.031
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => --------
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => --------
[local_ip] => --------
[local_port] => --------
```

With the multipart I was at least getting a 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **CURLFile** instead of curl_file_create() fixed the problem. Even though they are supposed to be the same...

Answer (score 0):

Don't built your own multipart. Curl is perfectly capable of doing that for you:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

it'll take an array and do whatever's needed automatically.

And if you're on PHP 5.5+, you can use [curlfile](http://php.net/curlfile) for the file part as well, without the `@` hack.

Comment: Either way it isn't working. I've updated the question.

Comment: Tried that as well.
string(0)